# Moving /dev/shm/ to /run/shm in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, tmpfs

Dolphin (The KDE4 FM) would not receive file change notifications for `/dev/shm`, but for `/run/shm`.

So now I would like to migrate `/dev/shm/` to `/run/shm`, but I couldn't find the corresponding part in systemd that handles it.

All I want is to simulate what Ubuntu does. Mount shm to `/run/shm`, and symlink it to `/dev/shm`.

Or was it possible with `udev` rules? I'm not sure if it's suitable here.

Comment: you can also bind-mount already mounted file system - `mount -o bind source destination` or `mount --bind ...`.